# Jest: How to test function that calls bind(this)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a Parent component that looks like this:

```
export class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { activeTab: TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW }
  }

  filterByNeedsReview() {
    const { filterByNeedsReviewFn } = this.props
    this.setState({ activeTab: TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW })
    filterByNeedsReviewFn()
  }


  render() {
    return (
        ...
          <FilterTab
            ...
            onClick={this.filterByNeedsReview.bind(this)}
          />
          ...
    )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test that the child was loaded with the right props. Originally I had it as an anonymous function: `onClick={ () => this.filterByNeedsReview() }` but I couldn't test that so I tried to move on to `bind(this)` instead.

However, I'm having issues mocking out the `bind` function:

```
  it('renders a filter tab with the right props for needs review', () => {
    const bounded = jest.fn()
    const boundedFilterByNeedsReview = jest.fn(() => {
      return { bind: bounded }
    })
    Header.prototype.filterByNeedsReview = boundedFilterByNeedsReview
    expect(
      shallowRender()
        .find(FilterTab)
        .findWhere(node =>
          _.isMatch(node.props(), {
            ... // other props
            onClick: bounded, //<-------------- FAILS WHEN I ADD THIS LINE
          })
        )
    ).toHaveLength(1)
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

Bind the method in the constructor to prevent the method from re-binding every time the component renders:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { activeTab: TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW }
    this.filterByNeedsReview = this.filterByNeedsReview.bind(this)
}
```

Then pass the bound method as a prop to the child:

```
<FilterTab
    ...
    onClick={this.filterByNeedsReview}
/>
```

You don't need to use an anonymous function here.

Comment: Nice. So in this case, `Header.prototype.filterByNeedsReview = boundedFilterByNeedsReview` wouldn't work right? I would have to stub out the instance `wrapper.instance().filterByNeedsReview = jest.fn()` instead?

Comment: @Edmund You could access the method like you mentioned, but you wouldn't need to reassign it with `jest.fn()`. Call the function as it is, then check that the state has been updated and that `this.props.filterByNeedsReviewFn` has been called.